# What happens to the Hamiltonian of the wave function after measurement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hamiltonian

As I understand it, the Hamiltonian is the kinetic plus the potential energy of the wave function. When a measurement is done what happens to the kinetic and potential energy?

Does it dissipate? Is it conserved in the measured state? Does it decrease?

Comment: The Hamiltonian is **an operator** that returns the kinetic plus the potential energy of the wave function, though I'm not sure how this is relevant to your question. Any measurement on a sytem requires an interaction with that system and therefore an exchange of energy between the system and the measuring device. If the energy of the system changes then the change is due to either energy being transferred to the measuring system or *vice versa*. The total energy is always conserved.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRennie that goes directly to my question. You said IF the energy of a system changes and I wanted to know DOES it change. Does the Hamilton or kinetic+Potential energy of the system(wave function) change when it is measured? Does the energy decrease and is transferred to the measuring device, does the energy increase and then the energy of the measuring device would decrease or does everything stay the same and there's no change of energy for the system or the measuring device?